# tiny_mce affect all the text area in my page

Tags: php, javascript

i downlaoded a tiny_mce folder and implemented it in my page. it's work fine, My problem is that all the textarea in my page looks like tiny mce , i want  only one textarea looks like tiny mce and left of all in normal textarea . what will i do to do this???

Please replay urgently

Thanks in advance...........

Comment: Of all the answers your **20** questions, have none solved your problems?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

maybe if you looked at the [tiny_mce site](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/index.php) and their [exhaustive and helpful examples](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/full.php) you would discover it's easily done via class attributes, if you so desire .. check [here](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/example_03.php)

Comment: -1, if someone asks a question here they expect an answer and not something like `go and read documentation you stupid idiot`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are finding tinymce hard to use there is an alternative called ckeditor at www.ckeditor.com. It is easy to customise though the default design is terrible but easy to change.